# Do points do anything in Celeste?

Tags: celeste

When Madeline collects a strawberry in *Celeste*, text appears above her head to show it was worth 1000 points. (Most likely an homage to old arcade games).

Do these points do anything? Does it add to a score total?

[image: Collecting a strawberry for 1000 points]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no score and no purpose to the points per se. However, there is a related Easter egg and achievement: collecting multiple strawberries at once (by not standing on solid ground too long) leads to increasing point values much like stomping enemies in a Mario game, and if you can collect six strawberries at once, the sixth counts as a "1 UP" and grants the achievement.