# Celeste- What did I miss?

Tags: celeste

**Am I missing something??**

I completed all the C-sides/B-sides. I want to make sure I got everything. I have all the hearts and strawberries. I tried checking walkthroughs but they all do speedruns. Are there any secrets I'm missing? I like knowing I completed/saw/got everything. I will play this game again in the future I enjoyed it so much but first I want to know if I missed anything.

Thanks!! (I know this is kinda a stupid question but I would appreciate hearing an answer from another player)

Answer (score 10):

(***Post-game spoilers below***)

Celeste has a few hidden secrets that aren't listed on the main menu.

## Golden Strawberries

In addition to the 175 red strawberries listed on the stats screen, there are 26 unlisted golden strawberries you can earn for a total of 201 strawberries.

After you've completed Chapter 8's B-side, a golden strawberry will spawn at the start of each chapter. To 'bank' the golden strawberry, you must beat the chapter without dying. You can earn 25 golden strawberries this way.

Chapter 9's winged strawberry is quite possibly the hardest challenge offered by the game, and not only because the chapter is quite long and difficult:

> After completing the final screen, there is a secret, very challenging screen that is only accessed if you are carrying the golden strawberry. You must beat this last challenge without dying before the golden strawberry will collect.

The final golden strawberry, known as the winged golden strawberry, can be earned by [completing Chapter 1 without dashing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OniVhi7z9Yw).

## Moon Berry

A 202nd strawberry can be found in Chapter 9, called the Moon Berry. It can be found:

> in the final screen, by backtracking a significant distance after destroying the battery.

## Hidden Developer Room

There is a [hidden developer room](https://nintendowire.com/news/2018/01/30/guide-uncovering-celestes-secret-developer-room/) containing characters from various indie games that Celeste's developer (Maddy Thorson) has worked on.

- In Chapter 6, select the *Reflections* checkpoint to start by a broken elevator.
- Air dash upward and climb the wall to the next screen.
- Next, jump and dash up to do a boosted wall-kick off the first small ledge on the left to reach and grab second ledge.
- Jump towards the right side to find an invisible alcove to recharge your dash.
- Finally, do a dash-jump across the pit, then dash upwards into another small invisible passage.

(For a full list of characters, see *[Who are the characters in Celeste's developer room?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/328013/181240)*)

#### Earn a 1-Up

You can earn an achievement for earning a 1-up by holding on to six strawberries and banking them at the same time.

(See *[Do points do anything in Celeste?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/326102/181240)*)

#### Sources

- [Neoseeker - Celeste Collectables](http://www.neoseeker.com/celeste/Celeste_Collectibles)
- [NintendoWire - Uncovering Celeste’s secret developer room](https://nintendowire.com/news/2018/01/30/guide-uncovering-celestes-secret-developer-room/)

*Feel free to edit this list if you know any secrets I missed.*